# Rename the button standard button save

Tags: visualforce, community, custom-object, urlhacking, button-overrides

Rename the button standard button save.
What is the best way? 
Is the URL hack? or VF page. For both I need a code.Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can not change Standard buttons name on Standard pages, but you can use your own button name on custom VF pages and on that custom button name you can perform standard save button action.
2. You can create a custom button and apply the same functionality through custom button.